# PHP [QUERY_STRING] truncated at carriage return

Tags: php, apache

first question on SO!

I am running a PHP 5.3.10 on apache 2.2.22.  I am only doing this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
file_put_contents('php://stderr', print_r($_SERVER, TRUE));
?>
</body>
</html>
```

the output in Apache's error.log looks like:

```
Array
(
[HTTP_HOST] => dns1
[PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
[SERVER_SIGNATURE] => <address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at dns1 Port 80</address>

[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
[SERVER_NAME] => dns1
[SERVER_ADDR] => 192.168.2.6
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[REMOTE_ADDR] => 98.210.76.128
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www
[SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@localhost
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/rcv.php
[REMOTE_PORT] => 51164
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
R5 HTTP/1.0_PROTOCOL] => R5000
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
[QUERY_STRING] => UID=3333&DATA=R5000
[REQUEST_URI] => /rcv.php/?UID=3333&DATA=R5000
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /rcv.php
[PATH_INFO] => /
[PATH_TRANSLATED] => /var/www/index.html
[PHP_SELF] => /rcv.php/
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1369084575
)
```

the incoming http request is of the form: (snippet from apache's access.log)

> 98.210.76.128 - - [20/May/2013:13:21:10 -0700] "GET /rcv.php/?UID=3333&DATA=R5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000\rR5000

(it's a series of sensor readings.  They are all "R5000" in this case.)

The `[QUERY_STRING]` and `[REQUEST_URI]` seem to get truncated at the first carriage return (\r), causing me to lose the rest of the sensor readings.  This is confirmed when I look at the $_GET values, only one sensor reading is present in the DATA field.

How can I avoid this or change this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot send a carriage return to a `GET` request. Try Using `Post` instead

Answer (score 3):

Parameters and their values should be urlnecoded, so instead `\r` in your url, you should use `%0D`